# Is it a sin for Rakshasas, Pisachas, and Asuras to kill humans?

Tags: sin, asuras, rakshasa, human

The armies of the Asuras (Daityas and Danavas), Rakshasas, and Pisachas frequently come to Earth and kill humans.

It is even said in scriptures that the food for Pisachas is human flesh.

Do these creatures sin by doing this?

Comment: If you know human flesh is food for them how can it be a sin? Is it a sin for tigers to eat deer-meat?

Comment: @Rickross very very pertinent question.

Comment: @Rickross Well Tigers don't have intelligence and so they don't sin, but Pisachas do.

Comment: @Rickross did u know that all tigers are fools?

Comment: If it is part of their food habit then it can not be sin .. because they can't live without it .. first survival, then questions like Dharma Adharma arise .. Smritis already make this clear @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Pratimaputra No, I don't .. any conscious beings have some sort of Buddhi

Comment: @Ikshvaku: A tricky question indeed.